# Using ggmap to visualize the location-based data in R

Tags: r, google-maps

I have a locational data frame in R like this...

```
cambridgeparking <- read.csv("camparking.csv")

ID     Location
1      85 BRATTLE ST Cambridge, MA (42.37587649000045, -71.12423110899965)
2      47 BRATTLE ST Cambridge, MA (42.37421138600047, -71.12166838499962)
3      130 HARVARD ST Cambridge, MA (42.3653084390005, -71.09376133099966)
```

Variable "Location" contains actual street name & longitude and latitude inside of the parenthesis.

In order to use ggmap to visualize the location based data, I have used these code to get the map of cambridge

```
cambridge <- get_map(location = "cambridge, MA", zoom=10)
cambridgemap <- ggmap(cambridge)
```

Then, I wanted to create a bubble chart with these locations

```
cambridgemap + geom_point(aes(x=Location, y=Location), data=cambridgeparking$Location)
```

After failing at executing this code, I have realized that R cannot identify the longitude and latitude in the data frame by simply setting x and y values as "Location".

Is there an way for me to use ggmap to create bubble chart with `cambridgeparking` data frame?

Comment: yes, you have to use string functions to split/extract the lon/lat values into two other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way. As hrbrmstr mentioned, you need to extract numbers for lon and lat here. In my case, I used the stringi package to do that job. Using mutate() from the dplyr package, I created two new columns (i.e., lon and lat). Then, I counted how many data point exist for each pair of lon and lat. For that reason, I modified your sample data. Using the count, you can control the size of bubbles when you draw a figure.

```
mydf <- data.frame(id = 1:6,
                   Location = c("85 BRATTLE ST Cambridge, MA (42.37587649000045, -71.12423110899965)",
                                "85 BRATTLE ST Cambridge, MA (42.37587649000045, -71.12423110899965)",
                                "85 BRATTLE ST Cambridge, MA (42.37587649000045, -71.12423110899965)",
                                "85 BRATTLE ST Cambridge, MA (42.37587649000045, -71.12423110899965)",
                                "47 BRATTLE ST Cambridge, MA (42.37421138600047, -71.12166838499962)",
                                "130 HARVARD ST Cambridge, MA (42.3653084390005, -71.09376133099966)"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)

mutate(mydf, lat = as.numeric(stri_extract_first_regex(str = Location,pattern = "\\d+\\.\\d+")),
             lon = as.numeric(stri_extract_last_regex(str = Location,pattern = "-\\d+\\.\\d+"))) %>%
group_by(lon, lat) %>%
summarize(total = n()) -> mydf2

#mydf2
#        lon      lat total
#      (dbl)    (dbl) (int)
#1 -71.12423 42.37588     4
#2 -71.12167 42.37421     1
#3 -71.09376 42.36531     1

cambridge <- get_map(location = "cambridge, MA", zoom=10)

ggmap(cambridge) +
geom_point(data = mydf2, aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = total))
```

If there is no duplication of the locations, you can do the following.

```
mutate(mydf, lat = as.numeric(stri_extract_first_regex(str = Location,pattern = "\\d+\\.\\d+")),
             lon = as.numeric(stri_extract_last_regex(str = Location,pattern = "-\\d+\\.\\d+"))) -> mydf2

ggmap(cambridge) +
geom_point(data = mydf2, aes(x = lon, y = lat))
```

[image]

Comment: I have sucessfully extract latitude and longitude as variables. However, when I tried to run the `cambridgemap + geom_point(aes(x=lon, y=lat, color="violation"), data=loc)`, it prints `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` as a result.. I do have lat and lon value which is used multiple times (for example, when the violation occurs in a same location twice). Would this be the problem? if so, any ways that i can fix it?

Comment: @MichaelCKang What is `violation`? Is that a variable you created?

Comment: @MichaelCKang If you have duplications, you may want to consider my first option. You basically need to count how many times each data point happens. For that reason, you use `group_by` and `summarize`.

Answer (score 0):

following on from the comment, something like:

```
ll <- stringr::str_match_all(cambridgeparking$Location, 
                    "\\(([[:digit:]\\.-]+),[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]\\.-]+)")

cambridgeparking$lat <- as.numeric(ll[[1]][,2])
cambridgeparking$lon <- as.numeric(ll[[1]][,3])
```

then use those lat/long values in `geom_point`. Note that at the '10' zoom level these points will overlap.